# Require modules globally in a Exppress JS app and use a router level middleware after the HTTP request

Tags: node.js, express

Bellow is the "users" module of my nodeJS application.

```
/**
 *  record.js
 */

var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router();

// Config.
var config = require('../config/config');

// Validator class.
var validator = require('validator');

// User module.
var User = require('../models/user');

// Error middleware.
var errors = require('../middleware/errors');

/**
 *  --- Crypto. -------------------------------------------
 */

var crypto = require('crypto'),
    key = config.secretKey;

var encrypt = function (data) {
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', key);
    var crypted = cipher.update(data, 'utf8', 'base64');
    crypted += cipher.final('base64');
    return crypted;
};

var decrypt = function (data) {
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', key);
    var decrypted = decipher.update(data, 'base64', 'utf8');
    decrypted += decipher.final('utf-8');
    return decrypted;
};

/**
 *  --- Register user. ----------------------------------------
 */

router.post('/user', function (req, res, next) {

    var email = validator.toString(req.body.email),
        password = validator.toString(req.body.password);

    if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
        res.locals.validationError = 'isEmail';
        return next();
    }

    if (!validator.isLength(password, 3, 20)) {
        res.locals.validationError = {
            'type': 'isLength',
            'minLength': 3,
            'maxLength': 20
        };
        return next();
    }

    // Generate a hash, from the passowrd.
    var hash = encrypt(password);

    User.create({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: hash
    }, function (err, user) {

        if (err) {
            res.locals.dbError = err;
            return next();
        }

        // Prevent exposing sensitive data.
        var data = {
            'id': user._id,
            'email': user.email
        };

        // HTTP 201 - Created.
        return res.status(201).send(data);
    });
}, errors);

module.exports = router;
```

I believe in best practices, which leads me to the following questions.

1. As you can see, I use dependency injection to require several other modules which the  "router" requires. (config, validator, etc.).

**I will basically need to require the **validator** module in every section of the app, and I am wondering if I can require it once globally and just reference it where I need it.**

**Basically, is requiring a module inn different modules of an application the way to go?**

2. I use a "error" middleware, you can see it in action after the POST request.
   If I'll have several HTTP requests in this module, is there a way I can inform express to use the middleware after each HTTP request, from a single place?

Something like the following, just that I want the middle ware to execute after the request, not before:

```
app.all('*', errors)
```

Right not the middleware executes before.

3. What do you think of the coding style of the module? How would you refactor it? What would you change? I am just learning NodeJS, this is my first server side API and I want to get good habits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I will basically need to require the **validator module in every section of the app, and I am wondering if I can require it once globally and just reference it where I need it.**

Yes, you can, with `global.validator = require('validator');`. However, this is not a best practice, it's a worst practice. The node practice of explicit dependency declaration is favored as it is more readable, easier to track during refactoring, and fails earlier when things go wrong. We have a huge body of browser code as evidence that splitting a project into module files makes things better and declaring each module's dependencies makes things better, so don't revert to the old browser style of a single concatenated file that gets dependencies as globals.

> I use a "error" middleware, you can see it in action after the POST request. If I'll have several HTTP requests in this module, is there a way I can inform express to use the middleware after each HTTP request, from a single place?

express has a built-in error handling middleware pattern you should read up on and use instead of this ad-hoc scheme you have built. To use it, pass an error to `next`:

```
if (err) {
  return next(err);
}
```

And code your `error` middleware as a 4-parameter middleware added after your main routes:

```
app.use(function error(err, req, res, next) {...});
```